# How do you detect a SwiftUI Color Picker closing?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to detect when the color picker is closed so I can update the color after the user is done editing instead of during editing.

I have tried using the onChange modifier and it works well when you select a color from the predetermined color palette, but when you use the sliders, the color picker is immediately closed and onChange function is called.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Please read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/colorpicker it takes a binding, so you can pass a binding and use the binding variable in code. If you are saving it to DB, have a separate Save button that would save it, so user can decide when to save it